# Push attributes to array by className?

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

Can someone please help me with how to push different attributes of elements with the same classname into an array? I'm not that good at Javascript and this is what I have tried but the arrays turns up empty.

One array should contain the URL of images and the other one is for image-texts in a span-element:

```
function slideShow(){
  imgUrlList.length = 0;
  imgTextList.length = 0;
  var imgUrl = document.getElementsByClassName('markedImg');
  var imgText = document.getElementsByClassName('marked');
  for(j=0; j<imgUrl.length; j++){
    imgUrlList.push(imgUrl.src);
  }
  for(k=0; k<imgText.length; k++){
    imgTextList.push(imgText.innerHTML);
  }
  openWindow();
}
```

Comment: You need to change `imgUrl.src` to `imgUrl[j].src` and `imgText.innerHTML` to `imgText[k].innerHTML`

Comment: they are defined as global variables

Comment: thanks for the answer, the arrays are now filled :) but does anyone know why I get this message "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL index.htm from frame with URL slideshow.htm. Domains, protocols and ports must match."

Comment: another script is suppose to get those arrays and show the pictures but it seems that the script cant find or read the arrays?

Comment: Is the URL inside the frame from a different domain? If so, then the Same Origin Policy would apply:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: now the page that is suppose to open up the slideshow is in the same folder as the index page...